# Use command output for "if then else" in batch file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I want to run this command and use the result as my "if then" statement

```
schtasks /query /s SERVER /fo list /tn "TASK" | find /c "Running"
```

I'm hitting a roadblock on how to manage this though.
The normal output for that command is either a `0` or a `3`.
I need to be able to say "if result 0 then goto " or something along those lines.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command **FOR** is the preferred method to get output lines of a command into a variable for further processing. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` for details on this command.

```
for /F %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /query /s SERVER /fo list /tn "TASK" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /c "Running"') do if "%%I" == "0" goto :EOF
```

The pipe operator `|` must be escaped with `^` to get it applied to command **schtasks** and not resulting in a syntax error because of applying it to command **FOR**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That was exactly what I needed.